# Android: NullPointerException from UP Button

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with a nullpointer exception when I return to a previous activity by using the UP button in the action bar.

I'll try to explain my flow:

ActivityA.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY, value);
startActivity(intent);
```

ActivityB.java:

```
Obj o = getIntent().getSerializableExtra(ActivityA.KEY);
o.doStuff();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

ActivityC.java:

```
// Do some stuff, then finish
finish();
```

Now all this works fine when I press a button on Activity C that triggers the `finish()`part.

The problem occurs when instead of pressing that button I press the UP button on the action bar to go back to Activity B. Then I get a nullpointer because he tries to recreate Activity B, and fails on the line `o.doStuff();`

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ActivityB}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can I solve this? How can I prevent the Activity B from needlessly recreating? Please keep in mind that I'm doing this Android stuff since Tuesday ..

Comment: What does the logcat go on to say after `java.lang.NullPointerException`? What's the rest of the stacktrace?

Comment: This is what happens in Android. Unless you do something in onPause() to save state, it'll call onCreate() again and your activity is recreated.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this might not be what you want but this scenario is not uncommon and what I find myself doing at times is `if (o == null)` in `ActivityB` I do `finish()`. This leads the user back to `ActivityA`. If `ActivityA` is not in the backstack, then the app finishes. This is what happens with **Instagram** at times. It's not perfect but it's not that annoying, I think.

If it's a must to go back to B, you could actually just transfer your Object in your intent to C. And before `finish()` in C, you could fire a new `StartActivity(B.class)` with Object as extras to B.

Comment: I think that the OP doesn't understand activity lifecycle in Android. Starting a new activity as you say is actually the problem to begin with.

Comment: Starting a new Activity shouldn't ever be a problem, right? The problem is the depandancy on getting Extras. But it would be great if @Kuurde could try it out?

Comment: It shouldn't be but OP is depending on an object reference to be there. At the very least, OP could check if an object == null and if so, recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Android Activity lifecycle. The problem is that starting a new Activity can destroy an old one in memory, and if you don't return to an Activity for a while its memory will be reclaimed. You need to take a look at onPause() and onResume() to see what you can do to save state.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

It's not that Android "needlessly" recreates the Activity, it does it all the time. If you change orientation, your Activity is destroyed and recreated. If you start a bunch of apps and Android needs the memory currently held by an inactive app, it'll be destroyed and will be recreated when you next launch it.

**As an aside, if you're not going to use the lifecycle callbacks onPause() and onResume(), you should at least check to see if your object is null and recreate it in onCreate().**